# collapsable menu under my navigation bar is not getting to the right side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i am trying to make a nav bar with its contents collapsable when turned to md size and, when collapsed the contents should be on the right side but am not able to do so someone help me, i also attached the code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-warning">
      <a href="" class="navbar-brand ms-md-4 ">PUbG Lite Reborn</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-md-auto me-4">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact-Us</a>
          </li >
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="" class="nav-link">Downloads</a>
          </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the link text to be right aligned, just add `.text-end` to your `.navbar-collapse`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-warning">
  <a href="" class="navbar-brand ms-md-4 ">PUbG Lite Reborn</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-md-auto me-4">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact-Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Downloads</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you want the `ul.navbar-nav` to be positioned on the right side (not 100% width and left aligned text), you can wrap the element with a flex container:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-warning">
  <a href="" class="navbar-brand ms-md-4 ">PUbG Lite Reborn</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end ms-auto">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-4">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact-Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link">Downloads</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: If you found it useful an up-vote would be appropriate. If it solved your problem you should accept the answer.

Comment: yeah sure, Actually i am new to stack overflow so i didn't knew i could do that to be good.